# How to add a new textbox in the div when I click kendo button?

Tags: jquery, html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am new to kendo UI. I have a `div` in the `HTML`:

```
<div id="newlabel"></div>
```

In this `div`, I want to add a new `label` with increasing number by using `kendo UI button`?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
    .Name("button name")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button",
                          @class = "k-primary", 
                          id = "NewButton",
                          param = "newlabel",
                          style = "height:1.9em;font-size:11px;margin-top:8px;"})
    .Content(NEW BUTTON")
    .Events(ev => ev.Click("Addlabel")))
```

Comment: I'm confused by the question you are asking here. As in the title you are asking how to add a new textbox when clicking a button then in the actual question you are asking how to add a label? Can you just clarify what it is you are actually after.

Comment: sry for making confuse, actually i have to add both textbox along with label in the div . the script was in separate file . so how to pass the div id to the javascript to append the label and textbox at run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have prepared a simple demo for you to test here: http://dojo.telerik.com/orOKI/3

This uses basically the same setup as the MVC Wrapper.

All you would need to do is add a @Data_target="{**YourDivIDHere**}" into the html attributes like so:

```
.HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button",
                          @class = "k-primary", 
                          @Data_target="MyDivHere", 
                          id = "NewButton",
                          param = "newlabel",
                          style = "height:1.9em;font-size:11px;margin-top:8px;"})
```

This will then load a `data-target` attribute onto button so you can then target the correct containing div. (It also means you can change the div if you want at a later date.

Then using the function I created `addItems` we have the following:

```
function addItems(e)
              {

                var target = $(e.sender.element[0]).data("target");
                $('#' + target).append('<div class="form-group">
                 <label class="col-md-2 form-label">I\'m a label</label>
                 <div class="col-md-10">
                 <input type="textbox" class="form-control" />
                 </div></div>'); 


              }
```

All this does is get the data-target attribute from the button if this is the only item on the page using this specific data attribute you could call that directly rather than navigating the button structure to get the id of it.

Then all i am doing is appending a label and textbox to the div and that it.

If you need any more info or your requirements are a bit more involved than this then let me.

**Note** you could always use a `kendo template` which makes it easier to edit in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place a `label` inside the `div` at runtime, you can use jQuery, like so:

```
$("<label id='testLabel'>Test</label>").appendTo("#newlabel");
```

You can change the contents of the `label` again using jQuery, like so:

```
$("#testLabel").text(number);
```